# Android: vibrator method (if phone has no vibrator?)

Tags: android, methods, vibration

I want to use the vibrator method in my app, and i have got it working on my phone which has a vibrator which is great. however phones that don't have a vibrator what happens. does it not work at all? does it stop the app working? or does it not show up in the market at all? or do i have to ask the phone if it has a vibrator?

I would also like to know if this code is good or needs any adjustments? here is my code..

```
Vibrator vi;

vi = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

vi.vibrate(100);

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" /> (In manifest)
```

Thanks, any help would be great.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check the docs, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html

all you need to do is check if a vibrator is present on the phone like so:

```
 Vibrator vi;

 vi = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

 if(vi.hasVibrator()){
     vi.vibrate(100);
 }
```

Because of the vibrate permission Android market *may filter* your app to just phones with a vibrate. To avoid this you can use the  tag with the attribute of required="false"

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
 <uses-feature android:name="there.isnt.a.vibrate.feature" android:required="false" />
```

It's all documented here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html

**HOWEVER**

There is not a Vibrate feature string, therefore Android Market **Will Not** filter your app because you are using the vibrate permission. So your ok to just use uses-permission and do the check in the Java code.

Devices need a vibrator to be compatible with the android market, but of course this doesn't go for the amazon and other app markets (Barnes & Noble Nook doesn't have a vib).

This is backed up by Dianne Hackthorn (Android lead dev at Google's) reply to this thread:
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/7713e796ea2d0f5f

Comment: Note that `hasVibrator()` was added in API Level 11. Devices older than that are mostly going to have vibration motors, particularly if they (legitimately) have the Android Market on them.

Comment: I have read the doc, and it says nothing about this. i am running on API 7 so i cant use "hasVibrator" so what happens if the vibrator is not present.

Comment: It'll just be ignored and not vibrate! You can use reflection to invoke the api lvl 11 call for those devices, depends how you want to implement your ideas.

Comment: Thanks very much, one last quick question, if the user declines the permission would it just miss the code out or would it stop the app from working?

Comment: A user can't decline a permission. They are just stated when a user goes to download your app.

Answer (score 3):

> does it not work at all? does it stop the app working?

Your vibration request should simply be ignored.

> or does it not show up in the market at all?

You cannot filter out devices from the Market that lack a vibration motor. Hence, the `VIBRATE` permission is not one of those where [if you ask for it imply a hardware feature](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions).

> or do i have to ask the phone if it has a vibrator?

You can, on API Level 11 and higher -- see Blundell's answer.

Comment: So if i am working on API 7 i can just keep everything as i have it now, because it wont be filtered out in the market and the phone should just simply miss it out if it does not have a vibrator?