# android - request permission not existed

Tags: android

Say, an app request VIBRATOR in manifest xml, and get vibrator service in code, but the device is not equipmented with vibrator. So, is it failed on installation or getSystemService returns a null pointer?

Thanks.

Comment: the app wouldn't even show on the play store. But if you sideload, and use vibration it would 1. maybe crash 2. or mybe do nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user is notified of the required permissions when they choose to install it from Android Market. Users don't get to choose to allow or deny this or that permission; they are notified of the permissions the app requires, and by choosing to install the app they are accepting that the require permissions will be granted.

You cannot filter out devices from the Market that lack a vibration motor because the VIBRATE permission is not one of those that imply [feature requirements](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer to your question is within this post [Android: vibrator method (if phone has no vibrator?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863363/android-vibrator-method-if-phone-has-no-vibrator)

This will check to make sure your app doesn't crash even if it is on a device without a vibrator.

```
 Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

 if(vibe.hasVibrator()){
     vi.vibrate(100);
 }
```

None the less Google Play filters apps so if a device does not have a vibrator, apps that require the vibrate permission in their manifest will not be available to install.